# SQL Query/ One to many relation where there isn't one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

To give a little background with what I am working with.  We use a custom application that gives sight into products being built between the time that it enters our ERP system as an order, to when it gets shipped.

Our ERP has a PRODUCT HEAD table and a PRODUCT DETAIL table.  The custom application we use, only looks at the PRODUCT DETAIL table.  So when it comes time to ship these products, they want to be able to see the ORDERS grouped together.

```
INSERT INTO @tmpTable (ordernum, linenum, model, customer, duedate, status, stage, repcode)

SELECT
    ct.ordernum,
    ct.linenum,
    et.model,
    et.customer,
    ct.duedate,
    ct.status
    ct.stage,
    ct.repcode
FROM CustomTable ct
LEFT JOIN ERPTable et On et.ordernum = ct.ordernum AND et.linenum = ct.linenum


Select Distinct
    top1.ordernum,
    top1.customer,
    (
        Select
            ISNULL(linenum, '') AS linenum,
            ISNULL(model, '') AS model,
            ISNULL(duedate, '') AS duedate,
            ISNULL(status, '') AS status,
            ISNULL(stage, '') AS stage,
            ISNULL(repcode, '') AS repcode
        From @tmpTable
        Where ordernum = top1.ordernum
        For XML Path('LineItem'), ROOT('root')
    ) As xmlinfo
From @tmpTable as top1
```

This is how I am currently handling this, I couldn't seem to figure out a better way to create a one to many relationship where there isn't one.  Rather than making separate calls to the DB for each order, I am just compiling all of the 'LINES' as xml.  The actual query is much longer and involves joining multiple joins with our ERP tables, which in turn slows the query down a bit.  I was wondering if the way that I doing this was efficient.

I thought maybe I could accomplish this using GROUP BY with SQL, but that doesn't seem to be the case, and I cant seem to find a good way to mimic the way you can group with an SSRS report using Angular.

I did a little digging around and it seems the way to accomplish this would be by using ng-repeat on  tag.

-- would it be better to handle the grouping on the HTML/Angular level? Or should I stick with grouping on the SQL Server side?

Comment: i miss the point about what is the criteria/rule used to identify which rows pertains to which order...

Comment: @LelioFaieta each row is identified by ordernum and linenum (which essentially make it unique).